# monitoring number of postgresql connections

Tags: postgresql, zabbix

I'd like to monitor on my Zabbix server the number of concurrent PostgreSQL connections, so I've created a cron job that outputs the COUNT of rows on the pg_stat_activity to a file, that will be read by zabbix once a minute.

My problem is that I might have a scenario where I get a COUNT of, say, 10, then have a quick peak of 50 connections, get back to 10, where I do the COUNT again.
  In this case the peak would not be noticed.

I've wondered about some counter being inc/dec each connection/disconnection, but failed to think how to do this.
  Also I could do the COUNT on a higher frequency and keep an average per minute, but this not solve the problem.

Any thougts in that matter?

Thanks,
Gabriel

Comment: You need to try and if you a specific problem post a minimal example here.

Answer (score 1):

Use log files. Here is a quick tutorial for Linux.

1)

Find out where if `postgres.conf` file located:

```
postgres=# show config_file;
┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
│               config_file                │
├──────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf │
└──────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

2)

Find and edit parameters in it (store the copy somewhere before):

```
log_connections = on
log_disconnections = on
log_destination = 'csvlog'
logging_collector = on
```

3)

Restart PostgreSQL:

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

(not sure but probably `sudo service postgresql reload` will be enough)

4)

Find out where the logs stored:

```
postgres=# show data_directory; show log_directory;
┌──────────────────────────────┐
│        data_directory        │
├──────────────────────────────┤
│ /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main │
└──────────────────────────────┘

┌───────────────┐
│ log_directory │
├───────────────┤
│ pg_log        │
└───────────────┘
```

5)

Almost done. In files `/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_log/*.csv` you will find records about connections/disconections. It is up to you how to deal with this info.